# UTMStack: Stack is creating zombie processes, about one a minute

Tags: utm

After installing as directed, I noticed when I logged in to the machine the next day that there were hundreds of zombie processes. Rebooting the machine clears them, but then more start being generated, it looks like about one per minute. Please advise.